# Detect logged in user in Facebook' Account kit (android)

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to verify phone number using Facebook Account kit sms authentication seamlessly.
However, access token is continously returned null. I am able to extract authorization code, through which I can get access token from rest api.

As per documents, I can assure that "Enable Client Access Token Flow" in Developer settings is ON.

What should be done to get output of:
AccessToken accessToken = AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken();
be returned non-null.

PS: on multiple logins without logout, sms with same codes are recieved.

Comment: I can provide sample code, just dont know for sure which section I should post here. Please post here if you suspect any particular area (manifest/ gradle/ Verfication Activity start/ or onActivityResult()..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never Mind, got it.. :D

The change was a simple oversight: I needed to replace:

```
AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE
```

with

```
AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN
```

Should have read documents more carefully.....

Comment: lol,, facing the same issues... and worked... thanks... yea, I think I need to read the doc more carefully... :D